# What is the name of this big tree with look of banyan branches?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

Location is India, Tree is so huge & some branches are hanging like Banyan.

[image]

Its Hanging Branches look:

[image]

& Finally its leaf:

[image]

So what is it then?

Comment: Looks like a fig, it has [large](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Leandro_Pederneiras/publication/280949439/figure/fig1/AS:284577005359130@1444859853879/Fig-1-Phylogram-generated-by-Maximum-likelihood-analysis-of-combined-ITS-G3pdh-and-ETS.png) number of species.

Comment: Did you find any fruits of the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Ficus, maybe F. benghalensis